# Adding google pay to Adyen Web SDK

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway, payment, adyen

I'm trying to add Google Pay as a payment method. I'm using [Adyen Web SDK](https://docs.adyen.com/developers/checkout/web-sdk).

I'm doing a CURL to get the payment session:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-API-Key: my_key" -X POST -d '{ 
       "merchantAccount": "my account",
       "sdkVersion": "1.9.2",
       "channel": "Web",
       "amount": { 
          "currency": "EUR", 
          "value": 2500
       }, 
       "reference": "Your order number",
       "countryCode": "IE",
       "shopperLocale": "en_IE",
       "origin": "http://192.168.43.16:3000",
       "returnUrl": "http://localhost:8080/payment/completed/the_guid_from_UI/"
    }' https://checkout-test.adyen.com/v41/paymentSession -i
```

Im copying the paymentSession into the UI. But on my page I just see:

[image]

All the documentation says to do is:

[image]

I've added the pay.js library. Is that it? What else do I need to do?

**EDIT**
I was using an older version of the Adyen Web SDK (which didnt support Google Pay). I've added the latest version now:

```
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/assets/js/sdk/checkoutSDK.1.9.2.min.js"></script>`
```

However Im still seeing the same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. You need to load the Google Pay library before loading the Web SDK.

```html
<script src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/assets/js/sdk/checkoutSDK.1.9.2.min.js"></script>
```

And just to be sure, have you done the step 2 on that screenshot?

> 2. Before you can start accepting live Google Pay payments, we need to configure your Google Pay `merchantID`. Follow [Google Pay's Deploy production environment guidelines](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/test-and-deploy/deploy-production-environment) then contact [Support Team](https://support.adyen.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) and provide your `merchantID` from your Google Pay Developer Profile.

Google Pay won't appear in the payment methods list if it's not properly configured in your merchant account.